# What are the concepts that I need to understand before studying Fourier Analysis?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, advice

**Background ( Long Story Short ) :**  For some reasons, I am taking a class in my university that focus on

- Fourier Analysis
- Laplace Transform, and
- Partial Diffiential Equations

**Problem :** I have done only basic level calculus such as differentiation (chainrule, product rule, etc) and that was 2 years ago. Now, after reading through the course materials, I find that it's totally incomprehensible andI believe this is because I do not have the necessary foundation in Mathematics.

What are the Mathematics concepts that I need to know before studying Fourier Analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be well versed in Ordinary Differential Equations, Boundary Value Problems, including Eigen Value Problems. Solving problems is very essential. You should also have studied a course on calculus.

Answer (score 2):

Its been a long while now but I know I would go to your book store by the Engineering books youll find a sparknote cheat sheet section pick up calc 2 & 3 as well as the diff eq.  It is the best way to cheat the foundation to keep up with the class. 3d coords and conversion of them ie polar. Vector. Scalar.  These were necessary to see id sets for choosing the transorm needed. The hardest part/foundation is recognizing the common questions.

Answer (score 2):

Besides calculus you should know complex numbers, trigonometric functions, Euler's formula. You can learn other concepts like sinc function, distributions, special functions (top hat fynction, dirac-delta etc.) while studying. If your calculus is good it is not that hard.